# cambiar fecha del formato ingles al español

Tags: python, datetime

me pusieron el ejercicio de abajo intento  hacerlo
con este código pero me da error , decirme como puedo hacer
este código en función al recibir la fecha se me imprima
como 20 de Abril del 2020

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.today(2020,04, 20, 16, 19,08.879057) #Creamos el objeto

format = dt.strftime(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day , dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second) #Le añadimos formato al datetime

print("{}" "\n{}" "\n{}" "\n{}" "\n{}" "\n{}".format(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day , dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second))
```

2. Crea una función que se llame formato_fecha() que reciba por parámetro una fecha del tipo datetime y nos devuelva el siguiente formato: "20 de Abril del 2020".

En muchas ocasiones nuestros sistemas están configurados de forma predeterminada en inglés, y no se puede cambiar la localidad a español. Por lo tanto, tenemos que aprender a seleccionar y mostrar los meses en español a pesar de que nuestro sistema se encuentre en inglés o en otro idioma. Crear una tupla para almacenar el listado de meses en español para poder seleccionar el nombre del mes adecuado en función a una fecha que le proporcionemos al programa. Queda prohibido utilizar métodos como `locale`, `setlocale` o `strftime`.

Prueba la función enviándole una fecha predefinida por ti y la fecha actual (now)

Comment: en primer lugar coloca el error que te da y segundo estas incumpliendo el punto 2 que te dice que no puedes usar `strftime`

Answer (score 1):

A ver, pues la cosa no es muy difícil, simplemente debes crear un diccionario cuyas claves sean la representación numérica de un mes y el valor sea el nombre del mes. Luego simplemente tienes que convertir la fecha que te pasan a un string, esto se puede hacer con `str(fecha)` o con *f-string* `f"{fecha}"` y luego simplemente separamos la fecha.

```py
def formato_fecha(date):
    fecha = f"{date}".split()[0] #obtenemos solo la fehca YYYY-MM-DD
    year,month,day = fecha.split("-") #separamos cada parte
    #creamos un diccionario con todos los mese
    months = {1:"Enero", 2: "Febrero", 3:"Marzo", 4:"Abril", 5:"Mayo", 6:"Junio", 7:"Julio", 8:"Agosto"}
    #retornamos el resultado
    return f"{day} de {months[int(month)]} del {year}"
```

**probamos**

```py
dt = datetime.today()
formato_fecha(dt)
```

**resultado**

```
31 de Julio del 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

La única dificultad es que tendrás que tener una tupla con los meses en español, tal como te dice el enunciado. No tiene complicación:

```py
def formato_fecha(fecha):

  meses = ("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio",
           "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre",
           "Diciembre")
  dia = fecha.day
  mes = meses[fecha.month - 1]
  anio = fecha.year

  return f"{dia} de {mes} del {anio}"
```